# remove non ASCII characters from NSString in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an app that syncs data from a remote DB that users populate.  Seems people copy and paste crap from a ton of different OS's and programs which can cause different hidden non ASCII values to be imported into the system.

For example I end up with this:

```
Artist:â â Ioco
```

This ends up getting sent back into system during sync and my JSON conversion furthers the problem and invalid characters in various places cause my app to crash.

How do I search for and clean out any of these invalid characters?

Comment: In a nutshell: create a new mutable string, iterate over all characters, check if it's an ASCII character and if so, append it to a the string.

Comment: In 2011 there's really no excuse not to handle unicode properly (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Remember that real people can and do have names like José or Müller or Jönsson or even Məmmədov or ბერიძე or 陈.

Comment: This "crap" letters from other languages than English. You should try to figure out the right encoding to preserve the letters.

Comment: turns out it wasn't those characters but some hexadecimal values I could not see

Comment: Those 'hexadecimal values' that you can't see will be components of multi-byte (Unicode) characters that your software isn't handling properly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While I strongly believe that supporting unicode is the right way to go, here's an example of how you can limit a string to only contain certain characters (in this case ASCII):

```
NSString *test = @"Olé, señor!";

NSMutableString *asciiCharacters = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSInteger i = 32; i < 127; i++)  {
    [asciiCharacters appendFormat:@"%c", i];
}

NSCharacterSet *nonAsciiCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:asciiCharacters] invertedSet];

test = [[test componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonAsciiCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", test); // Prints @"Ol, seor!"
```

Comment: No, because `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only trims the ends of the string, and therefore won't remove all the characters.

Comment: I agree that Unicode is the way to go. However in some cases this might still be valid. I have to generate QR Codes and I think that umlauts and the like are not ideal characters there.

Comment: Thanks, mate! This was brilliant.

Comment: @Cristik: sorry for making the changes, you were right, they're best added as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version of Morten Fast's answer:

```
NSString *test = @"Olé, señor!";

NSCharacterSet *nonAsciiCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet 
           characterSetWithRange:NSMakeRange(32, 127 - 32)] invertedSet];

test = [[test componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonAsciiCharacterSet] 
                          componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", test); // Prints @"Ol, seor!"
```

Notably, this uses `NSCharacterSet`'s `+characterSetWithRange:` method to simply specify the desired ASCII range rather than having to create a string, etc.

The results are identical, as comparing one to the other with `isEqual:` returns `YES`.