# problem with unicode in NSString

Tags: iphone, xcode, unicode, nsstring

i have string like: "YouTube         - ‪VID 0001‬‏" and i want the string like : YouTube - VID 0001  that means i want to remove the unicodes.

is there a way to remove unicodes like ‪ in iphone apps, if so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Does [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361586/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-nsstring-in-objective-c) and solution solve your problem?

I'd also recommend heeding the advice given in the comments on the linked question and making sure that you have a valid reason for not wanting unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you just want to remove the quotes (")

```
NSString *urString = @"\"YouTube - VID 0001‏\"";
NSString *formattedString = [urString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

Comment: not quotes...i have unicode like &#x202a; &#x202c; &rlm; in the string how can i remove these.